# How to add H2 to Wildfly, so I can see the data in the database?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jboss, wildfly, h2

I planned to use ExampleDS (java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS) for Java development before going to production. It is the default data source in Wildfly, configured using the embedded H2 database for developer convenience. I need to see the data in these tables during development. I am developing in IntelliJ. There is a ”database” tab to the upper right. I have previously added databases here and I could see their content. But I don’t know how to add the  ExampleDS database.

I then tried this approach instead:
1)  Deploy a prebuilt WAR-file for H2 Console: https://www.cs.hs-rm.de/~knauf/JavaEE6/kuchen/H2Console.war )

2) Open URL http://localhost:8080/H2Console/h2

3) login with username/password = "sa"

I could then access the H2 console.  It was however impossible to login with the default JDBC URL
java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS
I tried with name and password sa, but it always says "wrong password".

So I read the documentation on
https://developers.redhat.com/quickstarts/eap/h2-console/

It says:
To access the test database that the greeter quickstart uses, enter these details:

JDBC URL: jdbc:h2:mem:greeter-quickstart;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
User Name: sa
Password: sa

So I tried that and I could finally connect. But there seems to be no tables in the database. The documentation says:

Take a look at the data added by the greeter application. Run the following SQL command:

```
select * from users;
```

I tried that, but got the message

Table "USERS" not found

The tables that I have created in my JPA app can also not be found. I assume that is because my persistance file points to

java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS

So I changed it to

jdbc:h2:mem:greeter-quickstart;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1

Then I got this error when trying to run my JPA app from IntelliJ:

"WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.naming.context.java.jdbc:h2:mem:greeter-quickstart;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1"],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [

Does anypne know how I should proceed with this to actually add my tables to a H2 database and then to see the data in these tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't have some of the concepts clear: 
H2 has several options to create a database, using a file as basis or in-memory.

The in-memory is not stored in any place, for this reason if you configure it in your app like this:

```
jdbc:h2:mem:whatever
```

The jvm starts a database in their own memory, only available for the vm.

If you want to connect from outside I recommend to use the embedded or server mode.

Ofc an in-memory database will be empty, you have to populate it in start-up.

I used it a lot for testing. It's pretty cool.

Check the H2 cheatsheet:
https://www.h2database.com/html/cheatSheet.html

Comment: I have created a JPA-program, which creates the tables in an automatic way. I know that the tables are created, because I can make JPQL- searches from the tables and get search results (entity objects). My program is connected to the datasource java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS. Should not the tables be in that database then?

Comment: When you say ExampleDS you mean the jndi name?

Comment: Yes, I mean  <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS</jta-data-source>
  in the persistince.xml file.

Comment: <jta-data-source> contains the name of the jndi datasource, this should be declared inside JBoss.

Comment: maybe inside standalone?

Comment: <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS" pool-name="ExampleDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">

                    <connection-url>jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE</connection-url>

                    <driver>h2</driver>

                    <security>

                        <user-name>sa</user-name>

                        <password>sa</password>

                    </security>

                </datasource>

Comment: I tried to fit this code in my file, but I got "Element is not allowed here". So then I tried to make it work. I got this far, since the security and and connection tags were not allowed:  <jta-data-source>

            jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS"
            pool-name="ExampleDS" enabled="true"
            use-java-context="true"


        </jta-data-source> Here is my original tag: <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS</jta-data-source>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211951/discussion-between-lucbel-and-eyvind-almqvist).